# @yeild and @extends and @section is not working in my code in laravel 10

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

```
 @include('common.start')
 @include('common.header')
 @yield('main-master-content')
 @include('common.footer')
 @include('common.end')
```

this is main-master.blade.php file

```
@extends('main.main-master')
@section('main-master-content')   
@include('main.home.hero-sec')
@include('main.home.featured-catagory')
@include('main.home.featured-products')
@include('main.home.deals')
@include('main.home.customer-review')
@include('main.home.about-us')
@endsection
```

this is index.blade.php in home folder and main-master is in same folder as home folder but it's       not yeilding

## I was trying to yeild content but it's not working

Comment: could you please provide a schema of the `resources/views` directory?

Comment: try `@section('main-master-content')
    @parent
@endsection`. you can use the `@show` for yield

Comment: remove "your text ``"  before "@endsection"

Answer (score 0):

**Create your master layout (main-master.blade.php):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- Your header content goes here -->
        @include('common.header')
    </header>

    <main>
        @yield('content')
    </main>

    <footer>
        <!-- Your footer content goes here -->
        @include('common.footer')
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Extend the master layout in your view (index.blade.php):**

```
<!-- index.blade.php -->
@extends('main-master')

@section('title', 'Home')

@section('content')   
    <!-- Your individual page content goes here -->
    @include('main.home.hero-sec')
    @include('main.home.featured-catagory')
    @include('main.home.featured-products')
    @include('main.home.deals')
    @include('main.home.customer-review')
    @include('main.home.about-us')
@endsection
```

Make sure you are using the correct Blade directives **(@extends, @yield, @section)**